# Set canonical url as /en only for all routes of specific pages in nuxt-i18n

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I have a nuxt.js site with 5 languages (/en, /fr, /it, /es , /ar) and I need to manually set the canonical url for specific pages using the nuxt-i18n extension.
I only want my input to be visible as canonical url, for all the languages given. (When accessing a localized page /it/terms, I want the canonical to be /en/terms).

I have followed the documentation and placed the following inside the script section.

```
export default {
  head :{
    link: [
        { 
            href: 'https://example.com/en/terms', rel: 'canonical'
        },
    ]
  }
}
```

This successfully adds /en/terms as canonical to /it/terms, but /it/terms is still present as canonical url. Now I have 2 canonical urls for the same page.I only want the /en/terms as canonical.

Note: the same happens for all languages, not just /it

Comment: Can't you make a conditional based on the router?

Comment: How exactly ? can you provide a piece of code / configuration to add ?

Comment: `if (this.$router...)` mainly, with either your `link` or `null`.

Comment: Thanks, I know you're trying to help, but I couldn't see how this would solve my problem with nuxt-i18n. Since nuxt-i18n auto generates the routes and the meta descriptions, what I'm looking for would be what's inside the "if" block.. I want to prevent nuxt-i18n from auto generating the localized canonical for certain routes.
I forgot to add, I need a solution to work for static generation using the npm run generate

Comment: @kissu Any idea?

Comment: Not really then, sorry buddy.